# Submitting a form with ajax, when multiple instances of the same form are on a page

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I am battling with D8 ajax right now, hoping someone can shed some light on where I'm badgering this implementation.

The goal is to update a value based on the on the state of a checkbox.  The issue seems to be that there are multiple instances of this same form on the page.  However, I've confirmed they all have unique build ids.  They *do* have the same `$form['#form_id']`, but I think that's to be expected, `$form['#id']` is different.

Here is the code:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $widget = $form_state->getBuildInfo();
  /* @var $widget Factorywidget */
  $widget = current($widget['args']);

  if ($form_state->has('widget_id')) {
    $widget_id = $form_state->get('widget_id');
  }
  else {
    $form_state->set('widget_id', $widget->id());
  }

  $ajax = [
    'wrapper' => 'widget-toggle-status-wrapper',
    'callback' => '::ajaxRebuildForm'
  ];

  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="' . $ajax['wrapper'] . '">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  $form['toggle_widget_status'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => 'Toggle Status',
    '#default_value' => $widget->field_widget_status->value,
    '#ajax' => $ajax + ['trigger_as' => ['name' => 'widget_toggle_submit']],
  ];
  $form['widget_id'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $form_state->get('widget_id'),
    '#title' => 'widget ID is',
    '#size' => 10,
    '#disabled' => TRUE,
  ];

  $form['widget_toggle_submit'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#name' => 'widget_toggle_submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    '#submit' => ['::widgetToggleSubmit'],
    '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
    '#ajax' => $ajax,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['js-hide']
    ]
  ];

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Ajax submit handler that will return the whole form structure.
 *
 * @param array $form
 *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *     The current state of the form.
 *
 * @return array
 *   The form structure.
 */
public function ajaxRebuildForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form;
}

public function widgetToggleSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $widget = $form_state->get('widget_id');
  $form_state->setRebuild();
  /* @var $widget Factorywidget */
  //$widget = FactorywidgetService::toggleFactorywidgetwidgetStatus($widget);

  //return new AjaxResponse();
}
```

Again, there are multiple instances of this form on the page.  I added in `widget_id` as a textfield just to see if the widget Id was correct.  When *viewing* the page, widget ID in the textfield is correct:

[image]

The problem is, no matter what toggle I click, the `widget_id` in `$widget = $form_state->get('widget_id');` in `widgetToggleSubmit` is always the widget Id for the first form on the page.  I added a shuffle to the render array which displays these to confirm - it's always set to the first form on the page.

To, hopefully illustrate, this screenshot shows the Debugger for a breakpoint I put in `widgetToggleSubmit` at `$form_state->setRebuild()`:

The toggle has been triggered for the widget with id 3, but `$form_state->get('widget_id')` will only return the value for the first form on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by setting a custom form ID for each form. So you define your form like this:

```
class MyForm {
  protected $formId;

  public function __construct($formId) {
    $this->formId = $formId;
  }

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_form-' . $formId;
  }
}
```

Then, when you call your form, you pass a unique Form ID for each form:

```
$my_form = new MyForm('some-unique-id');
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($my_form);
```

Pass a different ID for each form on the page.

Comment: Wow, thanks - this worked, and I knew about the d8 alternative to `hook_forms` but I didn't do it, or give it a second thought, since the `form#id` was different in the source code.  The second one was automatically given `dashboard-toggle-widget-status--2`.  Thanks again!

Comment: If `FormInterface` is an interface, it should be `MyForm implements FormInterface`. Only an interface can extend an interface.

Comment: It works, thanks.
An improvement: in function getFormId() you have to use $this->formId instead of $formId:
return 'my_form-' . $this->formId;